# Webpack 3 --env logs properly but runs as unfdefined

Tags: webpack, environment-variables

Trying to get a different config based on a variable set in package.json

> Package.json:
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "webpack-main": "webpack --env.zone=configA --env.mode=development --config webpack.config.js",
>   },
> ```
>
> webpack.config.js:
>
> ```
> module.exports = env => {
>       console.log(env.zone); // outputs: configA
>       let t = env.zone; //causes: TypeError: Cannot read property 'zone' of undefined
> ```

Running into similar issues using yargs or setting variable direct in the command line.

My goal is to set these flags directly in package.json and have my webpack.config retrieve the proper config from another file.

Comment: This should work. Can you post your whole webpack config file?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference My problem was that I was that I running *webpack-dev-server* The type error was a result of the env variable not being set for that process.

Apparently you need to reset them for both: